# How to serialize/deserialize in Drools 7

Tags: java, drools

Hi im trying to deserialize rule here is code :

```
   DrlParser drlParser = new DrlParser();
        // Building package
        PackageDescr parse = drlParser.parse(false,myRule);

//         PackageDescr parse = drlParser.parse(rule,new StringReader(localDsl));
        // Saving byte array to DB
        byte[] streamOut = DroolsStreamUtils.streamOut( parse );


        // Kie server side
        // Fetching rules for each dealer and creating kie session
        ByteArrayInputStream ruleBinaryStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( streamOut );
        PackageDescr pck = (PackageDescr) DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(ruleBinaryStream);
        KnowledgeBuilderImpl knowledgeBuilder = new KnowledgeBuilderImpl();
        knowledgeBuilder.addPackage(pck);

        // Creating map with kiesessions
        final InternalKnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        kbase.addPackages( Arrays.asList(knowledgeBuilder.getPackages()) );
        KieSession kieSession = kieBase().newKieSession();
```

but got this error

```
InvalidRulePackage: Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='HDFC']
    KieTest/Rule_HDFC771392821.java (7:397) : orderObject cannot be resolved
```

when doing it with no serialization everything is working fine

Rule :

```
package KieTest;
import com.javatechie.spring.drools.api.model.Order;

rule "HDFC"

when
orderObject : Order(cardType=="HDFC" && price>10000);
then
System.out.println(orderObject.getPrice());
end;
```

Comment: Whatever that rule it's referring to has issues. Unfortunately you haven't provided any example of this rule named 'HDFC'.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas added rule

Comment: Does your `Order` class have a declared String variable `cardType` (or a `getCardType()` method which returns a String) and a declared integer variable `price` (or a `getPrice()` method which returns an Integer)?

Comment: The other thing I would suggest trying is removing the semicolon `;` at the end of the `orderObject` declaration. It's not clear if you're using mvel or java dialect, but that is something that the mvel compiler dislikes greatly.